# Loop only iterates once with `ssh` in the body

Tags: bash, ssh

I often see questions which are essentially the same as...

---

My `while` loop only iterates once when I call `ssh` in the body of the loop.

```
while read -r line; do
    ssh somehost "command $line"
done < argument_list.txt
```

---

Answer (score 7):

`ssh` also reads from standard input, so the first call to `ssh` consumes the rest of `argument_list.txt` before the next call to `read`. To fix, either redirect `ssh`'s standard input from `/dev/null` using either

```
ssh somehost "command $line" < /dev/stdin
```

or

```
ssh -n somehost "command $line"
```

In the event that `ssh` really *does* need to read from standard input, you don't want it reading more data from `argument_list.txt`. In this case, you need to use a different file descriptor for the while loop.

```
while read -r line <&3; do
    ssh somehost "command $line"
done 3< argument_list.txt
```

`bash` and some other shells also allow `read` to take a `-u` option to specify the file descriptor, which some might find more readable.

```
while read -r -u 3 line; do
    ssh somehost "command $line"
done 3< argument_list.txt
```